# Mysql left join derived table inconsistent result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement

When I perform left join from a derived table (a mapping table), I get different results

Here are the tables

```
Table_1

Date                    Value
2020-03-02 00:00:00      0
2020-03-02 07:00:00      1
2020-03-02 12:00:00      0

Table_2
2020-03-02 00:00:00      0
2020-03-02 07:00:00      1
2020-03-02 12:00:00      1
2020-03-02 14:00:00      0
```

```
Mapping_table
Date
2020-03-02 00:00:00
2020-03-02 01:00:00
2020-03-02 02:00:00
2020-03-02 03:00:00
...
```

Here is my query (I even added counters to check how mysql joins the table)

```
SET @prevValue=0;
SET @testCtr:=0;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(P.date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `date`, 
@prevValue,
D.value AS 'valueOriginal',
@testCtr AS 't1',
IF(D.date IS NULL ,@prevValue, @prevValue:=D.value) AS `dataValue` ,
@prevValue,
D.value AS 'valueOriginal',
(@testCtr:=@testCtr+1) AS 't2'
    FROM (SELECT `T`.`date` FROM `Mapping_table` AS `T`
     WHERE (date >= '2020-03-02 00:00:00') AND (date <= '2020-03-02 23:59:00')) AS `P`
LEFT JOIN `Table_1` AS `D` ON D.date=P.date ORDER BY `P`.`date` ASC;
```

Results to the following:

```
"2020-03-02 00:00:00"   "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"
"2020-03-02 00:01:00"   \N  \N  "3" \N  \N  \N  "4"
"2020-03-02 00:02:00"   \N  \N  "4" \N  \N  \N  "5"
"2020-03-02 00:03:00"   \N  \N  "5" \N  \N  \N  "6"
"2020-03-02 00:04:00"   \N  \N  "6" \N  \N  \N  "7"
```

Querying to Table_2 (I just replaced the query with Table_2) yields the following:

```
"2020-03-02 00:00:00"   "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"
"2020-03-02 00:01:00"   "0" \N  "1" "0" "0" \N  "2"
"2020-03-02 00:02:00"   "0" \N  "2" "0" "0" \N  "3"
"2020-03-02 00:03:00"   "0" \N  "3" "0" "0" \N  "4"
"2020-03-02 00:04:00"   "0" \N  "4" "0" "0" \N  "5"
```

I expect the left join from Table_1 should return the same as Table_2 result? I also don't understand why the counters are not same value? Is it because the two tables have different size?

Mysql version used 5.7

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL documentation is quite clear about this construct:

```
IF(D.date IS NULL ,@prevValue, @prevValue:=D.value) AS `dataValue` ,
@prevValue,
```

[Don't do it!](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1` evaluates `@a` first and then performs the assignment.

(This is from the 8.0 documentation but the same warning applies to all users of variables.)

This explains why the results are different -- you are requiring that the order of evaluation be in the order of definition, but MySQL *explicitly* says that you cannot depend on that.

This answers what you asked here.  If you want a safe version of the query, then ask a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.